# Schedule task to load BigQuery table into Apache Ignite

Tags: google-bigquery, ignite

I have a use case where we need to periodically load BigQuery table in to a cache and support SQL query from there. I'm doing researching on Apache Ignite and think it could be a good fit to our use case. Only that it's not clear to me yet how I can get auto-load from BigQuery. By "auto-load" I mean to keep Apache Ignite updated with BigQuery table data and let this updating transparent to applications. In most cases, our BigQuery tables are updated by other scheduled jobs/queries with intervals from 5 minutes to 1 month.

I'm new to Ignite, and I guess my questions are as the following:

1. Is this a feature supported in Ignite already? (I couldn't find any)
2. Or is there any exiting pluggins already? (I couldn't find any)
3. how to implement the auto-load cache for BigQuery using Ignite?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this once with Cache Store / loadCache(), but doing this every few minutes is infeasible. You may wish to design a BigQuery streamer to Apache Ignite, if it supports pushing of deltas.

Answer (score 0):

If Google BigQuery doesn't open its changelog files for CDC tools then find how to capture those updates differently and stream them to Ignite via its `IgniteDataStreamer` API. There should be a way to capture the changes with some pub/sub mechanism.